# Removing frame/plot borders from plot.im output

Tags: r, spatstat

I am plotting point density using the `plot.im` command in [spatstat](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatstat/index.html), and my output always has a frame around the plotted image that becomes thicker when I increase resolution for export. I tried `frame=F`, `axes=F`, `plot.frame=FALSE`, `bty='n'` but none of them seem to fix the issue. Anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

Use `box=FALSE` (see `?plot.im`: argument box, a logical value specifying whether a box should be drawn.):

```
Z <- setcov(owin())
tc <- colourmap(rainbow(128), breaks=seq(-1, 2, length=129))
plot(Z, col=tc)
```

[image: plot with box]

```
plot(Z, col=tc, box=FALSE)
```

[image: plot without box]